# MySQL 'group by' not grouping all data

Tags: mysql, group-by

I hope someone is able to help, it's possible I'm going about this all wrong. I'm far from proficient in coding but aim to muddle through.

I am trying to group results and am trying to join several tables that collate a users results and groups them by the teams they have played as.

For this I am trying to merge the results (scores) table, user (customers) and the teams tables (there are two; one identifying teams, and the second showing the teams picked by a user and the event at which the tean was picked).

I can output the results ordered by teams picked, however the results assigned to each team are for the users entire record (showing their total record across all games played), not just the record for the user as that specific team.

Please can someone point out a way to achieve this:

How do I get the results to show Points, games played etc based on the team_id only?

Thank you, here's my code

```
SELECT t.nickname                  AS Tm,
       @rownum := @rownum + 1      AS rank,
       t.player_image              AS IMG,
       t.customers_id              AS LINK,
       t.logo_image                AS PRO,
       te.team_name                AS PROD,
       ( Sum(CASE WHEN (g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id AND g.user_id_1_score >
         g.user_id_2_score)OR(g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id AND g.user_id_1_score
         <
         g.user_id_2_score)
         THEN 3 ELSE 0 end) + Sum(CASE WHEN (g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id OR
         g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id) AND g.user_id_1_score = g.user_id_2_score
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0 end
         ) )                       AS P,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id
                       OR g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id ) THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             end)                  AS GP,
       ( ( Sum(CASE WHEN (g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id AND g.user_id_1_score >
             g.user_id_2_score)OR(g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id AND
           g.user_id_1_score <
             g.user_id_2_score)
             THEN 3 ELSE 0 end) + Sum(CASE WHEN (g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id OR
             g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id) AND g.user_id_1_score =
           g.user_id_2_score
           THEN
             1 ELSE 0
             end) ) / Count(CASE
                              WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id
                                      OR g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id ) THEN 1
                              ELSE 0
                            end) ) AS AVP,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score > g.user_id_2_score )
                   OR ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id
                        AND g.user_id_1_score < g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS W,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score > g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS HW,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score < g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS AW,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score = g.user_id_2_score )
                   OR ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id
                        AND g.user_id_1_score = g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS D,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score = g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS HD,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score = g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS AD,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score < g.user_id_2_score )
                   OR ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id
                        AND g.user_id_1_score > g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS L,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score < g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS HL,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id
                    AND g.user_id_1_score > g.user_id_2_score ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS AL,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_1_score
             WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_2_score
           end)                    AS GF,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_1_score
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS HGF,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_2_score
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS AGF,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_2_score
             WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_1_score
           end)                    AS GA,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_2_score
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS HGA,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_1_score
             ELSE 0
           end)                    AS AGA,
       ( Sum(CASE
               WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_1_score
               WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id ) THEN g.user_id_2_score
             end) - Sum(CASE
                          WHEN ( g.user_id_1 = t.customers_id ) THEN
                          g.user_id_2_score
                          WHEN ( g.user_id_2 = t.customers_id ) THEN
                          g.user_id_1_score
                        end) )     AS GD
FROM   customers t
       LEFT JOIN scores g
              ON t.customers_id IN ( g.user_id_1, g.user_id_2 )
       LEFT JOIN teams_nom n
              ON t.customers_id = n.user_id_1
       LEFT JOIN teams te
              ON n.team_id = te.team_id
WHERE  t.customers_id = '1'
       AND ( g.game_event_id = '5'
              OR g.game_event_id = '6'
              OR g.game_event_id = '7'
              OR g.game_event_id = '8'
              OR g.game_event_id = '14'
              OR g.game_event_id = '17' )
       AND n.team_id = te.team_id
       AND user_id_1_score IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY n.team_id
ORDER  BY avp DESC,
          p DESC,
          gd DESC,
          gf DESC,
          tm ASC
```

Comment: `$query = "SELECT ...."; echo $query;` Also note that you're using a deprecated API

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i get a resource ID if i try to echo the query (and yes, I'll be moving the queries to mysqli)

Comment: Don't echo the query. Echo the string. See my example again.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence, I've put the string above

Comment: OK. There's so much here to talk about. Where to begin?

Comment: Haha, well i'm backwards engineering a full league table, perhaps i'll be better off going from scratch...

Comment: Yes. Let's trash this query and start again.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You might also take a look at: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=804

Comment: I'll get looking and rewriting, thank you